# Boost interprocess dont want to remove shared memory object before initialisation

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I have this base class for using shared memory. Boost examples use a remover struct as below to handle the shared memory. Which I have adapted for my *SharedMemBase* class

```cpp
//Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
   struct shm_remove
   {
      shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   } remover;
```

I dont want to remove the shared memory object on construction. In case another process is using it then i want to leave it as such.

Now if I leave the destructor only and if any unhandled exception occurs in main, then the destructor wont be called and hence my shared memory object wont be removed.

The next time I try to create the object the creation wont be successful as the shared memory object exists.

What I want to achieve with this is to have a single shared memory object with the input name. If any other process tries to **bip::create_only** with the same name then it should fail which can be done with my code below. The issue is when unhandled exceptions occur > destructor is not called > leaves the file in shared memory > Cannot create an instance of my class.

```cpp
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

class SharedMemBase
{
protected:
    bip::shared_memory_object shm_;
    const std::string name_;

    bip::shared_memory_object createShm(const std::string &name)
    {
        try
        {
            //this is what boost has in examples
            // dont want to remove shared object if another process
            // is using it.
            // bip::shared_memory_object::remove(name.c_str());
            return bip::shared_memory_object(
                bip::create_only, name.c_str(), bip::read_write);
        }
        catch (const bip::interprocess_exception &e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Shared memory object exists with name: "
                      << name << std::endl;
            throw e;
        }
    }

public:
    SharedMemBase(const std::string &name)
        : name_(name),
          shm_(createShm(name)) {}

    ~SharedMemBase()
    {
        //this is fine
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove(name_.c_str());
    }
};

int main()
{
    SharedMemBase shm_obj("name");

    throw std::runtime_error("Some random unhandled exception");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `open_or_create` instead of `create_only`?

Comment: Just tried it. What that does is, it opens the file from process 1 then process 2 is also allowed to open and write to it, which breaks my requirement (1 process with a shared memory name can create only 1 instance). It successfully finds and opens it though.